# Как автоматически выставить z-index?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

В данном примере z-index я прописал руками для каждого отдельного li.
Но я не знаю сколько будет разделов в меню.
Как можно автоматизировать выставление z-index с первого по последний LI ?

```css
.main-navigation-top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 66px;
}
.main-navigation-top li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -26px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    line-height: 66px;
    border-right: 2px #f0f3f8 solid;
    border-bottom: 1px #f0f3f8 solid;
    border-radius: 0px 33px 33px 0px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;

}

.main-navigation-top li:hover {
    background-color: #f0f3f8;   
}

.q { z-index: 3;}
.w { z-index: 2;}
.e { z-index: 1;}
```

```html
<nav class="main-navigation-top">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item q">Добавить</li>
    <li class="menu-item w">Редактировать</li>
    <li class="menu-item e">Удалить</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю сначала получить все элементы меню, а затем - применить к каждому из них z-index равен его порядковому номеру:

```
let menuItems = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item");

for (let i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
  menuItems[i].style.zIndex = i+1;
}
```

Comment: Как вариант, надеялся обойтись без JS  =)